# GraphLab Create with SFrame: Memory error

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

I'm trying to make an SFrame to analyze a folder 'amazon_baby.gl' with product reviews information for sentiment analysis. The folder is only about 40MB big and I have about a GB in memory. Yet I get an error:

> /home/anshudwibhashi/Coursera/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.so
>   in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.head()
>
> /home/anshudwibhashi/Coursera/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.so
>   in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.head()
>
> MemoryError: std::bad_alloc

I've read a few other posts and they recommend commenting out a certain line in CMakeLists.txt from the graphlab folder, but I can't find such a folder, in the first place...

Another thing is that SFrame is supposed to be a framework that would work in spite of having less memory (in comparison to pandas etc.) yet I'm getting this error. Please help!

Thanks!

EDIT:
I just checked I have about 800 MB free already!

Comment: Can you post a little more information about which command in particular caused the error?

Comment: what version of `graphlab/sframe` do you have?